# How Next.js routes are mapped to props.url?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

As seen in [README.md](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/blob/master/README.md), I'm trying to access `this.props.url`, but it's undefined, and I'm not sure how the component is supposed to get `next-routes` props. I would expect a `connect` or `withRouter` etc, but I've never seen `props.url`, and can't find any `import` mentioned in `README.md`.

How am I supposed to get `this.props.url`?

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this is a typo in the docs for `next-routes`. That package hasn't been maintained in quite a few months now and has not been updated for Next v7 or greater. Last supported was ^6.0.0.

Anyways, in NextJS, it should be attached via use of the `withRouter` HOC exported from `next/router`. Once you attach that, your query will exist on `this.props.router.query`.

Comment: The biggest pain is that `routes.js` config specifically has a `name` property that I can't access from within my component, which means I have to manually check the component's filesystem `/path` and `props.router.query` params for no reason

Comment: I can confirm that the usage of both `next-routes` together with `withRouter` , allows to receive the `router` prop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to return a url object in getInitialProps then you can access the query in the render function.

```js
export default class Blog extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps ({ query }) {
    return { url: { query } }
  }
  render () {
    // this.props.url.query.slug
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is the case, then it's possible one of our higher order wrapper components like `next-redux-wrapper` is overriding and removing it. Currently, `getInitialProps` is getting called with `({ Component, ctx, router })`